# ArrayList changes by changing its copy

Tags: java, arraylist

I am writing a code which needs to copy an arraylist but i am getting wrong answer after debugging i found that changing  a copy of arraylist is changing the original arraylist but i am not able to figure out why

```
static void iterDeep(int level,ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> current){

    if(current.equals(dest)){
        found = 1;
        printPath(current);
        return;
    }


    if(level <= 0)
        return;

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){

        for(int j=0;j<2;j++){
                ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> adj = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(current);
                if(j == 0){
                    for(int k=0;k<3;k++){

                        adj.get(k).set(i , current.get( (3+k-1)%3 ).get(i));

 // Here i am changing adj values but values in current are getting changed  

                    }
                    if(!map.containsKey(adj)){
                        map.put(adj,current);
                        iterDeep(level - 1 , adj);
                    }

                }else{
                    for(int k=0;k<3;k++){
                        adj.get(k).set(i , current.get( (k+1)%3 ).get(i));
                    }
                    if(!map.containsKey(adj)){
                        map.put(adj,current);   
                        iterDeep(level - 1 , adj);
                    }
                }

        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Short answer: with `new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(current);` you are only creating a new "outer" ArrayList, the inner ArrayList is still the same as before, thus containing exactly the same items as in your `current` list. Google deep clone versus shallow cloning. Deep cloning is what you need here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> adj = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(current);
```

produces a *shallow* copy of the list, meaning that although adding/removing elements of `adj` are not reflected in `current`, changing elements themselves have an effect on `ArrayList<Integer>` elements of both lists.

You need to make a method that creates a *deep* copy of the list, i.e. copies each individual list element into elements of `adj`:

```
static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> deepCopy(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> orig) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    for (ArrayList<Integer> inner : orig) {
        res.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(inner));
    }
    return res;
}
```